# Regex to validate decimals

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate the integers with the below pattern. Integer part can have up to 5 characters and the fraction value can have up to 2 chars. (fraction value is optional). Leading + or - is also optional.

```
(+/-) mmmmm (5).nn (2)
```

**Test data**

```
Valid
-1
+1
1
+.1
-.1
.1
+11111.11
-11111.11
11111

Invalid
+111111.11
-111111.11
+11111.111
-11111.111
11111.111
111111.11
+1.
-1.
1.
```

This is what I currently use

```
[+-]?\d{0,5}\.?\d{1,2}?
```

Is this correct? Am I missing something obvious?

Here is the [test case](https://regex101.com/r/qJEio9/1).

**EDIT**

If there is an additional constraint to have the number of digits from the scale is included in the precision.

For example DECIMAL(5, 2) defines numbers of the form 1234.5 whereas DECIMAL(5, 5) defines numbers of the form 1.2345. How should I change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
^[+-]?(?:[0-9]{1,5})?(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

- `^[+-]?` matches `+` or `-` at start, optional
- `(?:[0-9]{1,5})?` matches one to five digits, optional
- `(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$` matches a literal dot, followed by one or two digits at the end, optional. As the literal `.` is inside the non-captured group with the digits pattern following, it will only be matched when there are required digits afterwards

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJffot/1)

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, you can validate a number using

```
Number(n) === Number(n)
```

For any non-number values of `n`, like "abc" or `[1, 2, 3]`, `Number(n)` will return NaN. Given that `NaN !== NaN` in any case, you can easily tell if `n` is a number.

Number constructor works fine with almost any form of number representation:

```
Number(123) // -> 123
Number('123') // -> 123
Number('+12e+3') // -> 12000
Number('-1.2e-3') // -> -0.0012
Number('--123') // -> NaN
```

However, if you are constrained to using regular expressions, it's very close to what you described:

1. Optional "+" or "-".
2. 0 to 5 digits.
3. Optional "." and then 1 to 2 digits in decimal part. The whole part is optional, meaning that a single dot with no digits is invalid

And no exponential form.

That would be

```
/^[+-]?\d{0,5}(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

so that

```
/^[+-]?\d{0,5}(\.\d{1,2})?$/.test(123) // -> true
/^[+-]?\d{0,5}(\.\d{1,2})?$/.test('123') // -> true
/^[+-]?\d{0,5}(\.\d{1,2})?$/.test('+123.45') // -> true
/^[+-]?\d{0,5}(\.\d{1,2})?$/.test('--123') // -> false
/^[+-]?\d{0,5}(\.\d{1,2})?$/.test('-123.456') // -> false
```

---

Please note that the part `(\.\d{1,2})?` is whole optional. In your case, either dot or two decimal digits are optional, so "123." would be a valid number. In Javascript, it is valid, though, so there shouldn't be any problem with that.

Answer (score 1):

A slight modification in your regex works :

`^[+-]?[0-9]{0,5}?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`

or

`^[+-]?\d{0,5}?(\.\d{1,2})?$`

[Demo1](https://regex101.com/r/qJEio9/4)

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/qJEio9/5)